# Paginate table with inner joins

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need some help, I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    l.*,
    d.*,
    i.*,
    DATE_FORMAT(l.date_created, '%d/%m/%Y') as date,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(l.date_created) as ts,
    DATE_FORMAT(d.date_deposit_made, '%d/%m/%Y') as date_deposit_made,
    l.commission_introducer
FROM
    tbl_client_commissions_log l
INNER JOIN
    tbl_client_deposits d
INNER JOIN
    tbl_initial_commissions i
ON
    l.fk_deposit_id = d.pk_deposit_id AND i.fk_client_id = d.fk_client_id

WHERE
    d.date_deposit_made BETWEEN ? AND ? AND l.system_fee = '0'

AND
    l.fk_introducer_id = ?

ORDER BY ? LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
```

The problem is when I put a limit of say 10 and an offset of 0 to start it off. It only returns one row.

How do you paginate with inner joins betweem 2 tables?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simply try the `LIMIT` as:

```
  LIMIT ?, ?
```

where first param will be set to 0 and second will be set to 10 and you should get your results.

From MySQL Manual here:

> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15

Comment: Thanks @Yogendra, for some bizarre reason it didn't work the first time I tried. I have changed the SQL quite abit since posting this.